# How to get numerical output in `ip route` command

Tags: routing, iproute

When using `route` command, `-n` switch does the trick. How to get numerical output using `ip route` command? It's man page does not mention anything similar. Specifically I need `0.0.0.0` instead of `default`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the `-n` option of `route` is to suppress address-to-name lookups. It can be used for example to get the raw numerical information in case the lookups are too slow or returning incorrect results.

The `ip` command doesn't do address-to-name lookups by default, so it doesn't have or need that option. It *does* show the `0.0.0.0/0` entry as `default` for increased clarity, but that's just hardcoded, it's not based on a name lookup. There is a `-r` option to ask `ip` to resolve addresses to names, but it's not enabled by default. Essentially, `-r` is the opposite of `route`'s `-n`.

You can always pipe the output through `sed s#default#0.0.0.0/0#` if you don't want to see the word "default".